# probability at any point vs probability known location

Tags: false-discovery-rate

I am trying to compute a false alarm probability of a measurement. I have images so the (i,j) indexes of my image arrays are physical positions. I measure a signal at position (i0,j0).

In order to estimate the false alarm probability I check pixels which I selected to be comparable to the (i0,j0) pixel and count how many times a signal above 2 sigma is detected. This gives me the probability of my signal being a false alarm: e.g. out of 1 000 000 pixel 360 have a above 2 sigma detection (I think this is correct?).

Now I would like to include that I know where the signal is supposed to happen. Something like *'Knowing that 360 pixels of 1 000 000 pixel show a significant detection, what is the probability to measure such a significant signal exactly at position (i0,j0)?'*

Comment: Unless your images are completely white noise, I fear that any answer to this question would be either wrong or misleading.  The really interesting thing about images is that they have *structure* that is manifested as different statistical behavior at different locations.  Unless you account for that, it could be erroneous--and obviously so--to draw a conclusion about a particular location based on an analysis of all the locations.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I forgot to include that I explicitly look at pixels that are *reasonably* similar and my analysis of the noise yields that white noise dominates.